# Use map instead of recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, lambda

I have the following code, which takes a list, checks if each element's value is higher than the `avg` and, it that's the case, prints `val - avg`. I have already implemented it with recursion, I would like to transform it in order to use `map` function.

```html
loop [] = return ()
loop (x:xs)
      | x > average = print (x - average) >> loop xs
      | otherwise = loop xs
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: A good rule to live by is to factor out as much of your pure code as possible. In that spirit I would write `mapM_ print . foo where foo = map (subtract average) . filter (> average)`. It really helps to write the types of things you've already written, as well as the types of the things you want to write: so you say you want to use `map`, then what is the type of the function you intend to pass to `map`? It doesn't look like you've thought that far ahead

Answer (score 7):

Note that each step of `loop` does two things at once: they (possibly) generate a printing action out of each element of the list and then combine that action with the remaining ones (using `(>>)`). If you want to write `loop` in terms of `map`, you need to disentangle these two sub-steps. For instance, you can define a function...

```
printDiffIfAboveAvg :: Double -> IO ()
```

... and then apply it to all elements of the list with `map printDiffIfAboveAvg`. That will give you a list of actions, of type `[IO ()]`, which you will need to combine into a single overall action:

```
runAllActions :: [IO ()] -> IO ()
```

`runAllActions` already exists in the base library, in a more general version called `sequence_`:

```
sequence_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m ()
```

So you would have `loop = sequence_ . map printDiffIfAboveAvg`. In fact, there is also another function in the base library...

```
mapM_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m ()
```

... which performs exactly this combination of `sequence_` and `map`.